# Program crashes when input is too large in C

Tags: c, memory-management, input

Ultimately, the program takes in the number of times it should run, then the next number is how many numbers will be in each run, lastly it'll take in the input numbers. It will keep taking the average after each number until the end then print the highest average out of all the averages.

Example. It runs fine doing like a sample of 
2   <--- number of runs
 
10   <---- number of elements
10  ----- start of elements of first run
 
8
9
15
12
2
3
8
7
11 ----- end of elements of first run
3  ----- number of elements of second run
3---- start
2
1 ---- end

and the output comes out to
10.800000
3.000000

But I need it to be able to do around 500,000 to 1,000,000 elements and it crashes when doing just 5000~

how can I fix this? I'm not sure what parts may be causing the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double bestAverage(int* array, long int size);

int main(){

    long int i,n,j,k;
    double best;
    //number of cases
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    //process each case
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        //number of games played
        scanf("%ld",&k);

        //allocate memory
        int* scores = malloc(sizeof(long int)*k);

        for(j=0;j<k;j++){

            //score for each game played
            scanf("%d", &scores[j]);
        }

        best = bestAverage(scores,k);
        printf("%.6f\n",best);
        free(scores);
    }

return 0;
}

double bestAverage(int* array, long int size){

    long int i;
    long double average,sum = 0.0,highest = 0.0;
    //allocate memory
    double* averages = malloc(sizeof(long int)*size);

    for(i=0.0;i<size;i++){

        //total scores played so far
        sum = sum + array[i];
        average = sum/(i+1.0);
        //store each average
        averages[i] = average;
        //find the highest average of all the averages
        if(averages[i] > highest){
            highest = averages[i];
        }
    free(averages);
    }

return highest;
}
```

Comment: `averages` is freed too early

Comment: @timrau: That is correct, but why don't you make it into an answer? :)

Comment: `int* scores = malloc(sizeof(long int)*k);` : `long int` --> `int`, `double* averages = malloc(sizeof(long int)*size);` `long int` --> `double`: and `free(averages);` move to after for-loop.

Comment: @timrau Rather it is freed too many times than allocated also .

Comment: ohhh thank you, do you think someone can explain to me why it was able to work on smaller input sizes?

Comment: You don't need the allocated arrays.  You can calculate the sum as you read each row for a given data set, and then produce an average at the end.  You only need to keep the current best average and compare the new average with the current best.

Comment: It worked on smaller sizes by accident.  That's the dangerous thing about undefined behaviour — it can seem to work (by accident) until it doesn't.  It usually fails at the most inconvenient moment, such as demonstration for an extremely important customer and your boss's boss's boss.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler New to C and I suck at allocating so I figured I should try and write all my programs using them :P also appreciate the explanation!

Comment: There's nothing like practice.  I notice that no-one mentioned [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) yet — if it is available for your platform(s), it is an extremely powerful tool that would have told you precisely what was going wrong (access to recently freed memory).  There might also be '-fmemory-sanitizer` available to you.

Comment: that looks very promising and helpful for my future programs as I run into the problem where they are able to compile but there are still a handful of things wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bestAverage()`, array `averages` was freed in the first iteration. In later iterations, you were accessing freed memory.

You should move `free(averages)` one line later.

Also, as mentioned by @BLUEPIXY, you allocated incorrect size for both `scores` and `averages`.